# C++ Function and variable anomally

Tags: c++, function, variables

I'm using Code::Blocks to write a card game. I seem to be having trouble with this one function. For some reason, the variable 'card' gets jambled up somewhere in this. heres the code:

```
void prompt(int &space, int &card, bool checkS[9], bool checkC[4]){

do{
    cout << "\n\nSelect a card: ";
    cin >> card;

    if(checkC[(card - 1)] == true || card < 1 || card > 4)
        cout << "Invalid selection. ";

}while(checkC[(card - 1)] == true || card < 1 || card > 4);

do{
    cout << "\n\nSelect a space: ";
    cin >> space;

    if(checkS[(space - 1)] == true || space < 1 || space > 9)
        cout << "Invalid selection. ";

}while(checkS[(space - 1)] == true || space < 1 || space > 9);

cout << "\n\n";

cout << card << " / " << space << endl;

card -= 1;
space -= 1;

cout << card << " / " << space << endl;

checkC[card] = true;
checkS[space] = true;

cout << card << " / " << space << endl;
}
```

The 3 cout statements I made for testing. The first two cout's appear just fine but for some reason on the third one, the variable 'card' is some wacky @ss number. Any ideas?

Edit:
THis is how I'm calling he function.

```
prompt(boardSpace, cardFromHand, &checkS[9], &checkC[4]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is (mostly) fine. Most likely there's a problem with how you call it. In particular, `checkS` and/or `checkC` probably don't have enough memory allocated for them, which results in memory corruption when you try to modify them in

```
checkC[card] = true;
checkS[space] = true;
```

P.S. This is highly unlikely to have anything to do with your problem, but

```
while(checkC[(card - 1)] == true || card < 1 || card > 4);
```

should be

```
while(card < 1 || card > 4 || checkC[(card - 1)] == true);
```

In other words, check `card` *before* using it to index into `checkC`.

The same issue appears in several other places.

**edit** You say:

> I'm calling it like so:
>
> ```
> prompt(boardSpace, cardFromHand, &checkS[9], &checkC[4]);
> ```

If `checkS` and `checkC` are arrays of the correct sizes, the above should simply be:

```
prompt(boardSpace, cardFromHand, checkS, checkC);
```

Otherwise you're passing pointers to the *end* of both arrays, not to the beginning.

Comment: I see, I'll modify it accordingly.

Comment: also, I'm calling it like so: prompt(boardSpace, cardFromHand, &checkS[9], &checkC[4]);

Comment: @Arubix: This should be `prompt(boardSpace, cardFromHand, checkS, checkC); `.

Comment: That Worked! Thank you good sir. For some reason I thought you had to call it with the address symbol in order for it to save any modifications to the variable from the function.

Comment: @Arubix: Not for arrays, which are implicitly passed as pointers anyway.